# Is a language subdomain required instead of subdirectory for multilingual SEO?

Tags: multilingual

In my site, the multilingual path is look like:

e.g.
`www.example.com/en/index.html`

I want to ask is it necessary to use sub domain for SEO best practice?

e.g.
`www.en.example.com/index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google say you can use either:
https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites

Comment: it should be xxxual-websites.html instead of xxxual-websites.htm of the reference. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html